# Approximate piecewise linear function with finite incontinuities with polynomial on discrete points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, na.numerical-analysis

I wish to use single polynomial to approximate a piecewise linear discontinuous function. I wish to minimize the $L^\infty$ norm between such function and original function at every discrete point of function's range, and I do not care polynomial's shape at noninteger (or out of range) points whatsoever.

I see there is Remez's Algorithm with is optimal for minimizing $L^\infty$ error over a range, but it only targets smooth functions, and does not have special consideration over accuracy at discrete points.

One way would probably be polynomial regression over every point on the range of function, which considering it's piecewise linear just doesn't quite feel right ...

Is this a problem solved? Or is it solved when function is piecewise linear? Thank you so much.

For an example, please consider
$$f(x): \mathbb{Z}_{2001} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{201} = 
\begin{cases}
x & 0\leq x \leq 200\\
0 & x > 200
\end{cases}
$$